# I am trying to understand three sentences within this text.

Tags: grammar

I am having difficulty understanding the "sense" of three sentences from an older book.

The text comes from [Elements of Psychology: A Critical Examination of Locke's Essay on the Human Understanding, and in Additional Pieces](http://books.google.co.jp/books?id=Xm4XAQAAMAAJ&pg=PA171&dq=%22put+it+to+you+whether%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=xnMVU_bOM8OckAXv5YCoCQ&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22put%20it%20to%20you%20whether%22&f=false) (Cousin, 1864).  **(Note: the prior link will go straight to the page with the three sentences highlighted in yellow.)

Here are each of the three sentences.  The sentence structure is very difficult for me to understand. The original sentence is presented first, followed by my understanding:

**Sentence 1:**

> **ORIGINAL:** When you say, when you think, that the fire is the cause of the fluidity of the wax, I put it to you, whether you merely understand that the phenomenon of fluidity succeeds the phenomenon of the contact of fire?
>
> **My Understanding:** You understand only that the phenomenon of fluidity succeeds the phenomenon of the contact of fire?

**Sentence 2:**

> **ORIGINAL:** I put it to you whether you do not believe, whether the whole human race do not helieve, that there is in the fire an incomprehensible, an unknown something, which it is not our object here to determine, but to which you refer the production of the phenomenon of fluidity in the wax.
>
> **My Understanding:** You don't accept that there is something special in the fire that causes the melting?

**Sentence 3:**

> **ORIGINAL:** I put it to you, whether the conception of a phenomenon appearing after another phenomenon, is not one thing ; and the conception of a certain property in a phenomenon which produces the modification tested by the senses in the phenomenon that follows, another thing.
>
> **My Understanding:** You think "a phenomenon appearing after another one" and "something special in the fire causing the melting are the same thing?

Comment: I have updated the sentence clarify the question and make it easier to correspond each of OP's original sentence with OP's "understanding".  A **major** difficulty was that the OP only rephrased long fragments of the sentences instead of the entire sentences.  My understanding is that the OP actually understood the beginning of each sentence so OP focused on only the large fragment that OP did not understand.  If so, the OP should update the Question to simply rephrase each entire sentence.

Comment: I think this question is more appropriate for http://philosophy.stackexchange.com/ What the OP is asking is about [Locke's ideas on cause and effect](https://www.sparknotes.com/philosophy/lockeessay/section8.rhtml)

Answer (score 2):

## Answer to Question

I would say these are rhetorical questions. The following would be a simplified interpretation:<sup>1</sup>

- When people "understand" that fire causes wax to melt, that is a belief based on the trivial and non-refutable observation that we always see the fire first and the melting second. Right?
- Based on that belief of cause and effect, people naturally believe that something about the fire has a quality or ability that causes the wax melt. Right?
- These are two separate beliefs.  The first is the belief that one phenomenon appears after another phenomenon, which is gained through observation. The second belief is that there is some quality of the first phenomenon, not directly observable, which causes the observable effect of the second phenomenon.  These two beliefs are separate beliefs. As such, they must each be considered independently from the other.  Right?

<sup>1. Note that I am translating/transforming *semantically* with a wide latitude of creativity and expression in order to make clear what I believe the author intended.</sup>

---

## A quick primer on rhetorical questions

A [rhetorical question](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rhetorical_question) is one in which the speaker is suggesting a truth statement along with a "question" which is only a device to engage the reader/listener's mind to agree. The answer to the question is assumed to be, "Yes it is true." For example, given

`AssumedTruth` = Anything assumed true such as, "Water is needed for survival",

and

`Statement` = `AssumedTruth`.

Then all of the following have the same essential meaning:

- `Statement`. *(Assertion sentence.)*
- It's true that `Statement`. *(Explicit Assertion. Forceful.)*
- It's true that `AssumedTruth`, right? *(Rhetroical Question. AmEng.)*
- It's true that `AssumedTruth`, no? *(Rhetroical Question. Romantic Language Style.)*
- Is it not true that `AssumedTruth`? *(Rhetroical Question. Debate Style, Formal.)*
- Is not it true that `AssumedTruth`? *(Rhetroical Question. Awkward.)*
- Isn't it true that `AssumedTruth`? *(Rhetroical Question. Debate Style, Conversational.)*

The assumed answer to all of the above rhetorical questions is, **"Yes it is true that `AssumedTruth`."  However, the following are just questions (not rhetorical):

- Is it true that `Statement`?  *(Explicit question of truth. Could be emphasis; could be weak rhetorical.)*
- Is water needed for survival? *(Interrogative. Verb-Subject-Object.)*
- `Statement`? (Declarative Question. Rising intonation at the end.)

Answer (score 1):

No, your interpretation is not quite correct.

This is quite archaic language, and the meaning is not that clear, and arguably is grammatically incorrect.

If I were to "translate" this to modern English, it would be something like this:

> When you say that fire is the cause of wax melting, I would ask you
>   whether you simply believe that wax melts after it is contacted by
>   fire.
>
> I would ask whether instead, you believe that the fire contains some
>   unknown property which actually causes the wax to melt.
>
> I would ask you whether the concept of one phenomenon following after
>   another phenomenon, is different from the concept of a certain
>   property in the first phenomenon causing the second phenomenon.